# Ember.js - Not sure how to model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the RESTAdapter from Ember data to work with a JSON payload. Part of the payload contains data such as

```
"links": {
    "facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/dailypuppy",
    "twitter": "http://twitter.com/dailypuppy",
    "officialWebsite": "http://www.dailypuppy.com/"
},
```

I'm not really sure how to model the data. I noticed that the RESTSerializer has a `normalizePayload` function, so I figured I'd give that a shot instead of the RESTAdapter. I used it like so

```
normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    payload.facebookUrl = payload.links.facebook;
    payload.twitterUrl = payload.links.twitter;
    payload.mySpaceUrl = payload.links.myspace;
    payload.officialWebsiteUrl = payload.links.officialWebsite;
    delete payload.links;
    return payload;
}
```

Problem with this approach is the RESTSerializer doesn't support the `findQuery` method, which I rely on. I get an error saying `tried to load a query but your adapter does not implement findQuery`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing, I think, that you mis-use a serializer as (read: in place of an) adapter. This won't work. Don't do this. All kinds of evil will befall you.

You describe only part of the payload, so I assume that this is part of a json data object that conforms in every other aspect to the expectations of the [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) and [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html).

Now, overwriting normalizePayload as shown should work, **but** you don't use the RESTSerializer *instead of* the RESTAdapter. You replace the serializer *inside* the RESTAdapter. If you (using `ember-cli`) generate an application adapter (`ember g adapter application`) you can customize the serializer for your RESTAdapter like this (`app/adapters/application.js`):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.create({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
      function doNormalize(payload) {
        payload.facebookUrl = payload.links.facebook;
        payload.twitterUrl = payload.links.twitter;
        payload.mySpaceUrl = payload.links.myspace;
        payload.officialWebsiteUrl = payload.links.officialWebsite;
        delete payload.links;
        return payload;
      }

      // Change 'attractions' with other payloads here 
      if(Array.isArray(payload.attractions)) {
        payload.attractions = payload.attractions.map(doNormalize);
        return payload;
      } else {
        return doNormalize(payload);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

(code untested, but should show the idea)

Since, probably, not all your payload contains this `links` property, you may want to customize your the adapter only for a special `thing` - just replace `application` with `thing` in all I've written above, and you've got your specialized `thing` adapter. Everything that isn't a `thing` will continue to use the default application adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried placing the serializer inside the RESTAdapter but now I'm getting an error that says `Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined`

Comment: That means, that you've got some data without a `links` array. Maybe you've got something other than `thing`s to load and changed the application adapter and not the `thing` adapter. Or only some of the `things` contain the `links` array. Depending on that, use the `thing` adapter or put a check in `normalizePayload` if the `links` array exists.

Comment: I'm using mirage to mock out the data and verified that all the data contains a links array. I think the problem might be surfacing because when the adapter is being called (in this particular use case) multiple rows are getting returned (it's being called from a user search form). Since multiple rows are getting returned, `payload.links` is undefined whereas `payload.attractions[row_n].links` contains data. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. In general, `normalizePayload` should provide for both single records and array of records. I mistakenly assumed from your provided example, that you - in your application - could rule out arrays of records. To my defence, it was night in Germany. ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help. Still struggling to get it working with the array of records but I'll keep at it.

Comment: Looks very close. Looks like the doNormalize function never gets called though

Comment: Well, yes it did get called, but just on arrays. Fixed it.

Comment: It's not getting called for arrays. Possibly because payload is an Object but payload.attractions is an array? Weird thing is even if I change the conditional to `if(Array.isArray(payload.attractions)` doNormalize doesn't get called. I was able to verify it gets called though when payload.attractions isn't an array.

Comment: I missed the part about `payload.attractions`. You've got to call the map on the array. Fixed that as well.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. I officially owe you a beer should our paths ever cross ;)